# ἰχθύβολος ἄναξ, Fisher King (Greek)

Tags: greek

Would "[ἰχθύβολος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=i)xqu/bolos) ἄναξ" be a correct translation of "Fisher King" into Ancient Greek?
(I want to use a derivative of [ἰχθύς](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=i)xqu=s) plus ἄναξ, not βᾰσῐλεύς)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that's a reasonable choice under the constraints you have given (but see below for accent).  You might consider using ἰχθυοθηρητήρ rather than ἰχθυβολος.  I think the connotations are slightly different - although I don't think I've met either of these words in the wild, but from the formation, the -βολος suggests striking the fish, while the -θηρητήρ suggests hunting for them.

As an aside, the term "Fisher King" has quite Christian connotations for me, but the word for "fisherman" is ἁλιεύς in the NT, and ἄναξ has a distinctly poetic/archaic feel to it.

One further remark:  the link given above to the L&S entry for ἰχθυβολος shows *two* possible accents, a paroxytone ἰχθυβόλος for an active meaning, and a proparoxytone ἰχθύβολος for a passive meaning.  This type of distinction is regular for compound nouns of this type.  So, if you choose to go with your original version, it should be ἰχθυβόλος ἄναξ.

Comment: Thanks so very much. That's a very important distinction I missed - angling and fishing. So "ἰχθυοθηρητήρ ἄναξ" would be correct? And, to bring Draconis' excellent point into it, would "ἰχθυοθηρητήρ ϝάναξ" work as well?

Comment: I think that both I and Draconis have attempted to give you some reasonable possibilities, with indications of the connotations of the choices involved.  What is best for your purposes is up to you do decide.  Is ἰχθυβόλος (with its connotations of actually spearing that fish), or ἰχθυοθηρητήρ (with its connotation of hunting that fish) more suitable for what you want to convey?   Should you choose ἄναξ, or the still more archaic ϝάναξ?  This is a matter of tone where there is no "right" answer.  You must decide.

Comment: Sorry, but I should have answered your question: would "ἰχθυοθηρητήρ ϝάναξ" work as well?  I think so, with some qualifications.  I suspect that ἰχθυοθηρητήρ is relatively late, and ϝάναξ is definitely archaic.  Does this combination work together?  I'm not sure.

Comment: @varro ἰχθυοθηρητήρ ἄναξ / ϝάναξ it is, with that choice I'll have to make later. Thank you ever so much. Much obliged, friend.

Comment: Dear @varro I'm Alex, working at a Hong Kong Art and Design company. We're looking to build out own group of avid language enthusiasts to advise us. You are quite the knowledgeable, kind and helpful linguist, and I would like to ask if you'd like to join as a private adviser. We envisage an informal, unpaid advisory board (like StackExchange), except we can give credit on our (as of yet unmade) website, rather then Stack points. But if anyone can recommend a suitable payment system we're all ears. If you have any interest please let me know. All the very best, A. J. T. Whiteheart

Comment: Or, if you're not interested, please let me know here in comments. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to say “Fisher King” (a king who is a fisher, Roi pêcheur, Fischerkönig) and not “Fishing king” (a king who fishes) you will probably need to coin a compound, something like ἰχθυβολοβασιλεύς.

Comment: Does ἰχθυοθηρητήρ ἄναξ mean 'a King who Fishes' rather then Fishing King? If so, would ἰχθυοθηρητήρἄναξ work?

Comment: ἰχθυοθηρητήρ is a noun. In Greek if you combine two nouns (as opposed to adjective and noun) you need to use the compounding stem of the first noun.

Comment: Thanks. So what does ἰχθυοθηρητήρ ἄναξ become? I want to use ἄναξ rather then -βασιλεύς. ἰχθυοθηρητἄναξ?

Comment: *In Greek if you combine two nouns (as opposed to adjective and noun) you need to use the compounding stem of the first noun* -- that isn't right. Things like Ζεὺς ἄναξ, ἄναξ δεσπότης, βασιλεὺς ἄναξ are perfectly good Greek. http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Da)%2Fnac

Comment: @TKR Very interesting. But I had been interested in combining previous to it being mentioned so could somebody please tell me what it would be if combined (irregardless of whether I do so or not)? Thanks. ἰχθυοθηρητἄναξ?

Comment: @TKR. I think we are talking about two different things. Ζεὺς ἄναξ is apposition (Zeus the king). Fisher King is a compound where the first element is subordinate to the second.

Comment: But Fisher King is apposition too -- it means "the king who is a fisherman", not "the king of fishermen".

Comment: @TKR: I think it is a kamadhāraya “a king who is also a fisher”.

Comment: Aren't karmadhārayas appositional? Cf. examples in Smyth http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Smyth+grammar+986&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0007

Comment: @TKR So is ἰχθυοθηρητἄναξ correct?

Comment: @Johan88 ἰχθυοθηρητηράναξ might be technically correct by the rules of compounding, but it looks bizarre. Three-part compounds are rare in Greek, and so are compounds where the non-final element is a noun in -τηρ. I wouldn't go with a compound in this case.

Comment: @TKR Thanks do much. Exactly the advice I needed. Much obliged.

Comment: Dear @TKR I'm Alex, working at a Hong Kong Art and Design company. We're looking to build out own group of avid language enthusiasts to advise us. You are quite the knowledgeable, kind and helpful linguist, and I would like to ask if you'd like to join as a private adviser. We envisage an informal, unpaid advisory board (like StackExchange), except we can give credit on our (as of yet unmade) website, rather then Stack points. But if anyone can recommend a suitable payment system we're all ears. If you have any interest please let me know. All the very best, A. J. T. Whiteheart

Comment: Dear @fdb I'm Alex, working at a Hong Kong Art and Design company. We're looking to build out own group of avid language enthusiasts to advise us. You are quite the knowledgeable, kind and helpful linguist, and I would like to ask if you'd like to join as a private adviser. We envisage an informal, unpaid advisory board (like StackExchange), except we can give credit on our (as of yet unmade) website, rather then Stack points. But if anyone can recommend a suitable payment system we're all ears. If you have any interest please let me know. All the very best, A. J. T. Whiteheart

Comment: @TKR Or, if you're not interested, please let me know here in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Just to mention another option, I think the most natural translation would be ἄναξ [ἁλιεύς](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Da(lieu%2Fs). That's the normal Greek word for "fisherman", so would be the obvious choice unless you have some specific reason you need a compound with ἰχθύς.

Comment: Thanks so much. Great point, but in thus particular matter I am limited to ἰχθύς. Great point though.

Answer (score 1):

*Ánax* is a fine word for "king", though if you want to be super-ancient you can use *wánax* (*ϝάναξ*) instead; that's the even older form found in Homer. The first letter is a digamma, representing a sound that disappeared from Attic but survived in other dialects.

*Ichthýbolos* is specifically about hitting fish with spears or tridents; I'd translate it as "angler" rather than "fisherman".  Varro suggests a few other words you can use, but to add another option, how about a participle? The generic verb for "to fish" is *ichthyáō*, which doesn't imply any particular method. So "[the man who is] fishing" would be *ichthyõn* with contraction and *ichthyáōn* without; the contraction is very Attic, while Epic and many other dialects don't do that.

So for a particularly archaic sound, I'd say *ὁ ϝάναξ ὁ ιχθυάων* *ho wánax ho ichthyáōn* "the king who is fishing".

Comment: Thanks so very much. I had considered ϝάναξ but was a little worried about it precisely because it was so ancient and ϝ disappeared for a lot of Greece (but not all of it, for a long time). But I do require a title rather then a phrase, "Fisher King" rather then "the King who is fishing", in reference to the character of grail legend.

Comment: @Johan88 Greek doesn't draw as strong of a distinction as English does between "fisher" and "fishing"—both are basically "one who fishes".

Comment: @Johan88, FYI ϝάναξ does look rather nonstandard because of the digamma -- even in the texts of Homer digamma is not actually written, only reconstructed. If you're going for a recognizably Classical Greek form I'd go with ἄναξ.

Comment: Dear @Draconis I'm Alex, working at a Hong Kong Art and Design company. We're looking to build out own group of avid language enthusiasts to advise us. You are quite the knowledgeable, kind and helpful linguist, and I would like to ask if you'd like to join as a private adviser. We envisage an informal, unpaid advisory board (like StackExchange), except we can give credit on our (as of yet unmade) website, rather then Stack points. But if anyone can recommend a suitable payment system we're all ears. If you have any interest please let me know. All the very best, A. J. T. Whiteheart

Comment: @Draconis Or, if you're not interested, please let me know here in comments, thanks